# PostgreSQL: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery

Tags: python, postgresql, celery, amazon-rds

I fetch this error in my code , and my database is on AWS RDS instance.

`OperationalError: canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User was holding shared buffer pin for too long.`

and i found solution to change value of

```
max_standby_archive_delay = -1
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1
```

But AWS is not allow me to change those values . is there any other way to solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Move to something that does not restrict you that much.

Comment: perhaps you can redesign to have shorter-lived transactions.

Comment: my transection return around only 300 records , but i have more then 20milion record in that table , i have used indexing as well @Jasen

Comment: Try setting `hot_standby_feedback (boolean)` to true

Comment: @JustMe, it's already On

Comment: @KetanModi I have the exact same issue. Did you ever find a way to modify those parameters?